# Pure css opening specific accordion tab

Tags: html, css

I have code below for a content cycle and an accordion right below it (both created with Pure CSS). Is this possible with only css and html to make it so if a user clicks on select a top team from the cycle it will target the select a top team accordion tab and open it, and same with the other tabs? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.container1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

.ele, .arrow, .circle {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   margin: auto;
}

#one {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(0deg);
}
#two {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-60deg);
}
#three {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-120deg);
}
#four {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-180deg);
}
#five {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-240deg);
}
#six {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-300deg);
}


.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 105px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.ele:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
  zoom:1.009;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;
  left: -17px;
}

#two:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}
#three:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#four:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
#five:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  border-bottom-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(26deg);
}
#six:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  border-bottom-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#one:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-color: #006850;
}
#one:hover ~ .circle:after {
  border-top-color: #006850;
}

.circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -96px;
  left: -36px;
  background: #fff;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  top: -83px;
  left: -44px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.text1line {
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:14%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.text2line {
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:6%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.textcircle {
  font-size:17px;
  margin-top:37.5%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }

.top {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:13px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #005bab;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label:hover {
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #dce7f2;
}

.tab-content .container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  background: #f4f8fc;
}


/* :checked */

.input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 35em;
}

.input:checked~.tab-content .container {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Icon */

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.input[type=checkbox]+.label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.input[type=radio]+.label::after {
  content: "";
}

.input[type=checkbox]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="ele" id="one"><a class="text2line" href="">Select A Top Team</a></div>
    <div class="ele" id="two"><a class="text2line" href="">Get Off To A Great Start</a></div>
    <div class="ele" id="three"><a class="text2line" href="">Train For Success</a></div>
    <div class="ele" id="four"><a class="text2line" href="">Manage Work For Results</a></div>
    <div class="ele" id="five"><a class="text1line" href="">Grow Careers</a></div>
    <div class="ele" id="six"><a class="text2line" href="">Build A Deep Bench</a></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="circle"><a class="textcircle">Manager</a></div>
</div>
<br style="line-height:400px;"/>
<div class="top"> 
   <p> 
      <span style="font-family: verdana;"><strong>Click the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>+</strong></span><strong>&quot; to expand and the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>x</strong></span><strong>&quot; to collapse</strong></span></p> 
</div> 
<div class="wrapper">
  
  
  
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-one" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-one">Select A Top Team</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-two" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-two">Get Off To A Great Start</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        
        <p>Content goes here</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-train" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-train">Train For Success</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-manage" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-manage">Manage Work For Results</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-grow" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-grow">Grow Careers</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-build" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-build">Build A Deep bench</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="bottombar"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool little setup. May I suggest adding some transitions to your css hovers and consider a responsive design so that your top widget is on the left, with the accordion to the right for desktop browsers?

Comment: @RandyHall absolutely, I will try adding those next!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it already. Just change your `a`s to `label`s pointing to your appropriate checkboxes, like you do for the controls currently.

```css
.container1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

.ele, .arrow, .circle {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   margin: auto;
}

#one {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(0deg);
}
#two {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-60deg);
}
#three {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-120deg);
}
#four {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-180deg);
}
#five {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-240deg);
}
#six {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-300deg);
}


.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 105px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.ele:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
  zoom:1.009;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;
  left: -17px;
}

#two:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}
#three:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#four:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
#five:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  border-bottom-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(26deg);
}
#six:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: #006850;
  border-right-color: #006850;
  border-bottom-color: #006850;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#one:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-color: #006850;
}
#one:hover ~ .circle:after {
  border-top-color: #006850;
}

.circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -96px;
  left: -36px;
  background: #fff;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  top: -83px;
  left: -44px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.text1line {
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:14%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.text2line {
  font-size:15px;
  margin-top:6%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.textcircle {
  font-size:17px;
  margin-top:37.5%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }

.top {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:13px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #005bab;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label:hover {
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #dce7f2;
}

.tab-content .container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  background: #f4f8fc;
}


/* :checked */

.input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 35em;
}

.input:checked~.tab-content .container {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Icon */

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.input[type=checkbox]+.label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.input[type=radio]+.label::after {
  content: "";
}

.input[type=checkbox]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="ele" id="one"><label class="text2line" for="tab-one">Select A Top Team</label></div>
    <div class="ele" id="two"><label class="text2line" for="tab-two">Get Off To A Great Start</label></div>
    <div class="ele" id="three"><label class="text2line" for="tab-train">Train For Success</label></div>
    <div class="ele" id="four"><label class="text2line" for="tab-manage">Manage Work For Results</label></div>
    <div class="ele" id="five"><label class="text1line" for="tab-grow">Grow Careers</label></div>
    <div class="ele" id="six"><label class="text2line" for="tab-build">Build A Deep Bench</label></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="circle"><a class="textcircle">Manager</a></div>
</div>
<br style="line-height:400px;"/>
<div class="top"> 
   <p> 
      <span style="font-family: verdana;"><strong>Click the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>+</strong></span><strong>&quot; to expand and the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>x</strong></span><strong>&quot; to collapse</strong></span></p> 
</div> 
<div class="wrapper">
  
  
  
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-one" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-one">Select A Top Team</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-two" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-two">Get Off To A Great Start</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        
        <p>Content goes here</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-train" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-train">Train For Success</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-manage" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-manage">Manage Work For Results</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-grow" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-grow">Grow Careers</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-build" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-build">Build A Deep bench</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
              <p>Content goes here</p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="bottombar"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh yes awesome, thanks so much mate, cheers! (I will upvote when I can again, I reached my daily)

Comment: How would I make it so when you click the cycle it opens the tab and scrolls down to it? Would that just be adding href="#id"?

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki yes, essentially. You might have to put an `a` inside the `label` to make that work... honestly not 100% sure